# Why bind() doesnt work with jQuery 'query' as handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im learning JS and I wonder - why this is does not work?

```
$(function(){
$('#mydiv').bind('click', $('#myanotherdiv').remove);

});
```

Comment: You're *passing* the `.remove` method. When invoked, its `this` value will be a DOM element, while the method expects it to be a jQuery object.

Comment: Give this a try: `$('#mydiv').bind($.proxy($('#myanotherdiv'), "remove"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#mydiv').bind('click', $('#myanotherdiv').remove);
```

2nd argument is supposed to be a handler for the event

```
$('#mydiv').bind('click', function() { $('#myanotherdiv').remove() });\
```

And **.remove** is a method and not a property

So should be written as `.remove()`

Comment: I know, that enclosing it in `function` makes it work, but why it does not work in original variant - `$(...).remove` - is a function, right?

Comment: *"And .remove is a method and not a property..."* It is a property that references a method, so OP is passing a handler as the second argument.